# How to configure cloudkitty in devstack

Tags: juju, openstack

I need some documentation or guide which demonstrates me the installation of cloudkitty in my openstack Devstack.

I have tried installing the same using the following guide:

https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/CloudKitty/Devstack

But It doesn't seems to be working.

Actually its showing error as follows while setting up itself.

I am not getting cloudkitty setted up.

When I am trying to setup using cloudkitty in following command error is occurring:

```
enable_plugin cloudkitty https://github.com/stackforge/cloudkitty master 


/opt/devstack/.localrc.auto: line 46: enable_plugin: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [CloudKitty documentation](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/CloudKitty), and/or the [project page](https://github.com/stackforge/cloudkitty).

Comment: Already went through it ,there only I got the way to execute the same.
But I was getting error when I am trying to follows the same.That is why I have opened this question with the error message I got.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using juno try using kilo release instead

see:
https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/81710/how-to-configure-cloudkitty-in-devstack/

Comment: While details from this link may answer the question it is preferable to include the details of the solution in your answer in case the link goes down.